# How do I show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bbb{P}(|X_n|>n)<\infty$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-calculus

Let $X_i:\Omega\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random variables. Let $Z$ be another random variable such that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k(\omega)}{n}=Z(\omega)$$almost everywehre.

I could show that $\Bbb{P}(|X_n|>n~~\text{infinitely often})=0$. Now I need to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bbb{P}(|X_n|>n)<\infty$. My idea was the following:

Since $\Bbb{P}(|X_n|>n~~\text{infinitely often})=0$ there exists $n_0\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $|X_{n_0+k}|\leq n_0+k$ for all $k\geq 0$. Hence $\Bbb{P}(|X_{n_0+k}|> n_0+k)=0$ for all $k\geq 0$. Therefore $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bbb{P}(|X_n|>n)=\sum_{n=1}^{n_0-1} \Bbb{P}(|X_n|>n)\leq \sum_{n=1}^{n_0-1}1=n_0-1<\infty$$

**Update**
In a short discussion I have remarked that this solution is wrong. There is a thinking error because this $n_0$ depends on $\omega$. So I have that $|X_{n_0(\omega)+k}(\omega)|\leq n_0(\omega)+k$ for some $\omega\in \Omega$ but we do not know if $n_0$ is a uniform bound over all $\omega$'s. So that's the problem.

I have posted another solution below which should work!

Comment: $n_0$ depends on $\omega$ (the sample space element for which $|X_{n}(\omega)| > n$ doesn't happen infinitely often), and therefore is a potentially unbounded quantity.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer but I mean can it really be infinity? I don't think so because then $\Bbb{P}(|X_n|>n~~\text{infinitely often})$ would be $1$

Comment: $n_0(\omega)$ is finite for all $\omega$ for which $|X_n(\omega)|>n$ happens only finitely often. However, there is no guarantee that $n_0$ is *uniformly bounded* over all $\omega$. The actual conclusion is correct, but you have to use the fact that the $X_n$ are independent (and then use the second Borel-Cantelli lemma). Perhaps I'll write an answer.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Ah I see so the problem is the uniform boundedness for all $\omega$ we know it for specific ones but not for all right?

Comment: Correct. In any case, I'll write an answer because I want to be more specific than that.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer you don't need to write one if you don't want because I have found other solutions using borell cantelli and doing a contradiction

Comment: I see, then I'll avoid doing it. Consider writing a self-answer  (or you can just wait until someone else answers, I'll guess.)

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I'll write a self answer.

Comment: Sure, thanks, I'll take a look at it when you're done.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer done

Comment: Thanks. Since this is a solution-verification, you basically need to comment on your own attempt and why it was wrong. You can take whatever you need to from my comments. I voted up both Q and A.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Perfect I will also comment my attempt.

Comment: Sure, once again let me know when you're done.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I also updated my original question

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my answer to the exercise.

Let us assume that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Bbb{P}(\Lambda_n)=\infty$ where $\Lambda_n=\{|X_n|>n\}$. Now since all $X_i$'s are independent we also get that $\Lambda_n$'s are independent. Hence we can apply Borel-Cantelli $2$ and get that $\Bbb{P}(\lim\sup_n \Lambda_n)=1$. But this contradicts the assumption that $\Bbb{P}(\Lambda_n~~\text{infinitely often})=0$. Hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Bbb{P}(\Lambda_n)<\infty$.